# How to simplify $ [(f+g)^+]^2 + [(f+g)^-]^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given a function $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, let $h^\pm = \max \{\pm h,0\}$ denote the positive and negative part of $h$ respectively.

Let $f, g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. I am trying to understand if there is any relation which holds as equality (not inequality!) for the quantity
$$ [(f+g)^+]^2 + [(f+g)^-]^2.$$

I have checked on my own that $(f+g)^+ \neq f^+ + g^+$ (unless they are both nonnegative), but I am a bit confused while finding a relation which helps me to simplify that quantity.

Anyone could please help with that?

Answer (score 3):

We have: $$[(f+g)^+]^2 + [(f+g)^-]^2 = ((f+g)^+ + (f+g)^-)^2 - 2(f+g)^+(f+g)^- = |f+g|^2$$
where the last equality comes from the simple fact that either the positive or negative part has to be equal to $0$, thus the product $(f+g)^+(f+g)^-$ has at least one factor which is zero.

Comment: An the proof works for an arbitrary function $h,$ that is, $(h^+)^2+(h^-)^2=|h|^2.$

Answer (score 3):

You can take the following approach:

\begin{align}[(f+g)^+]^2(x) &= \begin{cases}
((f+g)(x))^2,&\ \ \ (f+g)(x)\geq 0\\
0,&\ \ \ (f+g)(x)< 0
\end{cases}\\
[(f+g)^-]^2(x) &= \begin{cases}
0,& (f+g)(x)\geq 0\\
(-(f+g)(x))^2,& (f+g)(x)< 0
\end{cases}\end{align}
therefore,

\begin{align}([(f+g)^+]^2 + [(f+g)^-]^2)(x) &= \begin{cases}
((f+g)(x))^2,& (f+g)(x)\geq 0\\
(-(f+g)(x))^2,& (f+g)(x)< 0
\end{cases} = |f+g|^2(x).\end{align}

Comment: This approach should generalize to proof that $F\circ f^+ + F\circ f^- = F\circ |f| + F(0)$. Thus, there is nothing special about squaring.